# Error missing type javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery in spring?

Tags: java, spring, websphere

There is application on spring4 + jpa deployed on websphere
When try to stop and start application on server, there are error messages in logs:

There is error message logs from websphere application server:

```
[2/11/19 15:22:43:087 MSK] 000000ae SystemErr     R [CompoundClassLoader@c29c9165] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery
when weaving type org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureAttributeSource
when weaving classes
when weaving
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[2/11/19 15:22:43:918 MSK] 000000ae SystemErr     R [CompoundClassLoader@c29c9165] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
[2/11/19 15:26:32:831 MSK] 000000ae SystemErr     R [CompoundClassLoader@c29c9165] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type javax.persistence.EntityGraph
when weaving type org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Jpa21Utils
when weaving classes
when weaving
```

Can you hint me, what about this errors?

my pom.xml is:

I think, this issue somehow linked with jpa

```
    ...
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <hb.enity.manager>4.2.21.Final</hb.enity.manager>
        <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>myAPP</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SERVLET-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JACKSON AND XML-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--DATABASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.odb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--APACHE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--LOG4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

websphere version  8.5.5.13
spring 4
database is oracle 11g

One of my JPA entities is

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "UserRecord", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name", "surname", "UserType"})})
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class UserRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "PR_KEY")
    private String prKey;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = false)
    private String name;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "UserType", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String UserType;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "User", length = 100000)
    @Lob
    private byte[] User;

    public UserRecord(String name, String surname, String UserType, byte[] User) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.UserType = UserType;
        this.User = User;
    }
}
```